# PHP object _construct function

Tags: php, oop, object

I have the following code

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">

<title>Objects</title>
</head>

<body>

    <?php

    class firstClass
    {
        function _construct($param)
        {
            echo "Constructor called with parameter $param";
        }
    }

    $a = new firstClass('one');
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

When i run this code nothing is outputted in the browser, the tutorial i am following says this code should output "Constructer called with parameter apples", what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor should be __construct() with two underscores.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

And it will output "Constructor called with parameter one" in your code.

Comment: No problem, we were all newbies at one point. Glad I could help. Can you mark my answer as the correct one?

Comment: Actually shouldn't he echo $a aswell? Looks like he's only creating the object

Comment: @icecub No, he's echoing in the constructor.

Comment: @gnarly it says i have to wait five more minutes but i will when the time is up

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a '_' in the [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) definition.

> function _construct($param) => defines a function called _construct
>   with one parameter 
> function __construct($param) => defines custom
>   constructor with one parameter

The code should be like this:

```
<?php

    class firstClass
    {
         function __construct($param)
        {
            echo "Constructor called with parameter $param";
        }
    }

    $a = new firstClass('one');
?>
```